# How to get back the control of the screen/keyboard on my Linux system

Tags: linux, keyboard, freeze, console, xorg

I have a Linux system running (Debian). It is working perfectly from a remote point of view. I can `ssh` in it, it has the `imap` running correctly, and a couple of `kvm` systems running (I can also `ssh` to them). Well, it works!

But when I go in front of the keyboard/mouse/screen there's nothing. No way to switch between the consoles with `Ctrl+Alt+F#` (X is not running on this system). The screen is desperately black. But the screen does not go to sleep mode, it still has its green led on! I guess it means that the graphics card still sends the H and V syncs correctly (VGA connection).

Is there a process that is blocking the display and prevents me from getting the control?

What's happening?

Note: Last time I used the console, it was in console 1. `Ctrl+Alt+F1`.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have a similar problem on an Ubuntu 8.04 machine, and do this:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> (for instance) to switch to another console, wait a couple of seconds, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back to the GUI.

In particular it seems to happen on the login screen, where moving the mouse or pressing a key doesn't seem able to wake up the screensaver sometimes.

OFF-TOPIC UPDATE: For anyone who's arrived here searching for X solutions, I tracked down the fix I had to do to get the ctrl-alt-F# keys to work in Ubuntu 8. Some edits to xorg.conf, that I'd blogged about here:
http://darrendev.blogspot.com/2009/04/screen-keeps-going-blank.html

Comment: Thanks Darren. I already tried switching consoles, being *very* patient.

Comment: I know there was one machine (I think it was that Ubuntu 8 machine actually) where the ctrl-alt-F# functionality was not built-in, but needed installing! Another idea is, from your ssh session, try killing X. Perhaps it just died of boredom and a young, fresh X instance will be more responsive?

Comment: `X` is not even running on this machine ... It is only a console issue!

Comment: @Didier Trosset Ah! Sorry, I missed that it was console-only. I only ever get a similar problem with X/gnome.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose, some things I would try: turn off screen blanking, ssh in and see if any suspicious processes are visible in top/htop, restart getty from an ssh session, check syslog, check daemon.log. Also simply try unplugging and replugging the keyboard if it's USB.

Comment: Thanks CarIF, "turn off screen blanking" failed. "ssh in" shows me the `bash` running in the console, killed it unsuccessfully. "syslog" and "daemon.log" don't show anything unusual. Already "unplugged" the PS/2 keyboard/mouse.

Comment: How about restarting getty? I'm wondering about a hardware fault. Can you try a *different* keyboard/mouse?

Comment: Restarted all 6 getty processes. Still the same. Keyboard/Mouse is OK, they are used in a KMV switch that works perfectly for other systems.

Comment: Could still be a bad cable, but I'm conceding this is really unlikely. Have you tried another *monitor*/monitor cable? If the monitor is detecting signal but showing nothing, it's very possible it's either faulty or not receiving the (VGA?) signal correctly.

Comment: Oh: I've had problems in the past with bad ports on a KVM. Can you try directly plugging in, or a different set of ports?

Answer (score 0):

changing the foreground terminal by means of `chvt` often works for me

```
# chvt 1
```